# Python Dict : How can I get a ordered difference set from dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get difference set from two dicts below:

```
dict1 = {'area':1, 'ip':1, 'device_name':1, 'max_value':1, 'min_value':1, 'ave_value':1}
dict2 = {'area':1, 'ip':1, 'device_name':1, 'max_value':1, 'min_value':1, 'ave_value':1, 'res_1':1, 'res_2':1, 'res_3':1, 'res_4':1, 'res_5':1}
```

And I wanna get ordered result like this:

```
result = {'res_1', 'res_2', 'res_3', 'res_4', 'res_5'}
```

I've found a way to get difference set:

```
result = dict2.keys() - dict1.keys()
```

But the output is not what I want:

```
[output:]
{'res_3', 'res_1', 'res_4', 'res_2', 'res_5'}
```

Unfortunately, It is always been a random order .

Comment: Sets are inherently unordered. What you seek is not coherent.

Comment: Worst case, convert your set into a list and sort it.

Comment: If you want a dictionary which has keys in the order of the result variable you gave, you can do,     difference_dict = sorted(difference_dict.keys())

Comment: result = [key for key in dict2 if key not in dict1]

Comment: Well, you mean that you do not want a 3rd party library. Then, you are out of luck and have to use a comprehension + sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store things in a set in order, but you can use a list and easily calculate the difference yourself. Using a list comprehension to do it neatly:

```
result = [key for key in dict2 if key not in dict1]
```

`key not in dict1` is an O(1) operation so the whole thing is O(n) just like regular set difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a sorted set, you will have to ressort to a third party library such as Sorted Containers: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html

Comment: I've never noticed this `sorted collections library` , thx for ur post.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are unordered. You can either sort it before you store it in the `result` variable, but then the type will be list.

```py
result = sorted(dict2.keys() - dict1.keys())
```

Otherwise you can sort it before you use it, so you can keep the type of `result` as set.

```py
result = dict2.keys() - dict1.keys()
print(sorted(result))
```